# Need help whenIntegrating complex UIView with SwiftUI failed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried to test a waving animated UIView that is runloop based on SwiftUI using ''UIViewRepresentable'' but it does not appear to be animating at all.

Using UIViewRepresentable Protocol to connect swiftui to UIView.

Swift UI Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WaveView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WaveUIView {
        WaveUIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: WaveUIView, context: Context) {
        view.start()
    }
}

struct WaveView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WaveView()
    }
}
```

The "Waving" UIView that I tested working on UIViewController way of doing it.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WaveUIView:UIView {

    /// wave curvature (default: 1.5)
    open var waveCurvature: CGFloat = 1.5
    /// wave speed (default: 0.6)
    open var waveSpeed: CGFloat = 0.6
    /// wave height (default: 5)
    open var waveHeight: CGFloat = 5
    /// real wave color
    open var realWaveColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            self.realWaveLayer.fillColor = self.realWaveColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    /// mask wave color
    open var maskWaveColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            self.maskWaveLayer.fillColor = self.maskWaveColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    /// float over View
    open var overView: UIView?

    /// wave timmer
    fileprivate var timer: CADisplayLink?
    /// real aave
    fileprivate var realWaveLayer :CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    /// mask wave
    fileprivate var maskWaveLayer :CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    /// offset
    fileprivate var offset :CGFloat = 0

    fileprivate var _waveCurvature: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var _waveSpeed: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var _waveHeight: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var _starting: Bool = false
    fileprivate var _stoping: Bool = false

    /**
     Init view

     - parameter frame: view frame

     - returns: view
     */
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        var frame = self.bounds
        frame.origin.y = frame.size.height
        frame.size.height = 0
        maskWaveLayer.frame = frame
        realWaveLayer.frame = frame
        // test
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    /**
     Init view with wave color

     - parameter frame: view frame
     - parameter color: real wave color

     - returns: view
     */
    public convenience init(frame: CGRect, color:UIColor) {
        self.init(frame: frame)

        self.realWaveColor = color
        self.maskWaveColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        realWaveLayer.fillColor = self.realWaveColor.cgColor
        maskWaveLayer.fillColor = self.maskWaveColor.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(self.realWaveLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.maskWaveLayer)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    /**
     Add over view

     - parameter view: overview
     */
    open func addOverView(_ view: UIView) {
        overView = view
        overView?.center = self.center
        overView?.frame.origin.y = self.frame.height - (overView?.frame.height)!
        self.addSubview(overView!)
    }

    /**
     Start wave
     */
    open func start() {
        if !_starting {
            _stop()
            _starting = true
            _stoping = false
            _waveHeight = 0
            _waveCurvature = 0
            _waveSpeed = 0

            timer = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(wave))
            timer?.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
        }
    }

    /**
     Stop wave
     */
    open func _stop(){
        if (timer != nil) {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
    }

    open func stop(){
        if !_stoping {
            _starting = false
            _stoping = true
        }
    }

    /**
     Wave animation
     */
    @objc func wave() {
        // when view is not visible
//        if overView?.window == nil {
//            print("not playing cause not visible")
//            return
//        }

        if _starting {
            print("started")
            if _waveHeight < waveHeight {
                _waveHeight = _waveHeight + waveHeight/100.0
                var frame = self.bounds
                frame.origin.y = frame.size.height-_waveHeight
                frame.size.height = _waveHeight
                maskWaveLayer.frame = frame
                realWaveLayer.frame = frame
                _waveCurvature = _waveCurvature + waveCurvature / 100.0
                _waveSpeed = _waveSpeed + waveSpeed / 100.0
            } else {
                _starting = false
            }
        }

        if _stoping {
            if _waveHeight > 0 {
                _waveHeight = _waveHeight - waveHeight/50.0
                var frame = self.bounds
                frame.origin.y = frame.size.height
                frame.size.height = _waveHeight
                maskWaveLayer.frame = frame
                realWaveLayer.frame = frame
                _waveCurvature = _waveCurvature - waveCurvature / 50.0
                _waveSpeed = _waveSpeed - waveSpeed / 50.0
            } else {
                _stoping = false
                _stop()
            }
        }

        offset += _waveSpeed

        let width = frame.width
        let height = CGFloat(_waveHeight)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        var y: CGFloat = 0

        let maskpath = CGMutablePath()
        maskpath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))

        let offset_f = Float(offset * 0.045)
        let waveCurvature_f = Float(0.01 * _waveCurvature)

        for x in 0...Int(width) {
            y = height * CGFloat(sinf( waveCurvature_f * Float(x) + offset_f))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: y))
            maskpath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: -y))
        }

        if (overView != nil) {
            let centX = self.bounds.size.width/2
            let centY = height * CGFloat(sinf(waveCurvature_f * Float(centX)  + offset_f))
            let center = CGPoint(x: centX , y: centY + self.bounds.size.height - overView!.bounds.size.height/2 - _waveHeight - 1 )
            overView?.center = center
        }

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))

        path.closeSubpath()
        self.realWaveLayer.path = path

        maskpath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        maskpath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))

        maskpath.closeSubpath()
        self.maskWaveLayer.path = maskpath

    }



}
```

I expect the SwiftUI to have the view animating and correctly have the frame/border changes according animation. But it is not animating at all right now.

Following is the animated view with UIViewController:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cardView.start()
    }

    func viewdidload(){
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.8, height: view.bounds.height * 0.5)
        cardView = HomeCardView(frame: frame, color: .gray)
        cardView.addOverView(someUIView())
        cardView.realWaveColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        cardView.maskWaveColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        cardView.waveSpeed = 1.2
        cardView.waveHeight = 10
        view.addSubview(cardView)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to addOverview in update uimethod

```
func updateUIView(_ view: WaveUIView, context: Context) {
    let overView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    overView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.addOverView(overView)
    view.start()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Adding OverView only makes the overView animating. But the frame of the wave view is not animating. When running with the UIViewController, there should be two waves that replaces the wave view bottom borders! In another word the view itself should be waving xD

Comment: can you post uiviewcontroller code, i want see the animated waves

Comment: Hi I have edited my question to include the code :P

Comment: you should add HomeCardView otherwise code will not compile

Comment: Oh Sorry HomeCardView is the same as WaveUIView. I only changed the name. Just replace HomeCardView with WaveUIView